# Masking in power BI

Tags: oracle, security, powerbi, masking, data-masking

In my power Bi dashboard I need to mask the data based on user who logs in,

1. Can this be done in dashboard level by calling oracle user defined function?
2. If I use a flag in oracle DB view itself can power bi dashboard display masked values based on the flag?

I am trying to find masking option in power bi desktop for direct query method